# Destroy all instances of component except one Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have popup component. It is imported in many places in my application. Is it possible to destroy all popup components when opening another one? So if I open one popup component all other should close. I thought about service which can store all previously opened popups but it's a bit tricky for me that's why I am wondering if it's possible to do this another way?

Comment: You can create `popupService` for any needs and keep opened states here. Or if you use Angular Material, you can just  do `dialogRef.closeAll()`.

Comment: Ok but actually what should I send to this service? And how to destroy my PopupComponent via this service? I tried send ComponentRef<PopupComponent> and destroy calling this.onDestroy() but without success.

Comment: Use method `clear` in your popup's `ViewContainerRef`